# Specify ninja version in Meson?

Tags: meson-build

I'm running Elementary OS, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Ninja is at version 1.3.4.  When running Meson, I get the error:

```
ninja: fatal: ninja version (1.3.4) incompatible with build file ninja_required_version version (1.5.1).
```

According to http://www.mariocampos.io/blog/meson,-first-impressions/ I can fix this by getting a newer version of Ninja.  That's fine, I can do that.  However, I prefer to keep to the software in the package repos, so my question is:

Can I tell Meson to generate a Ninja build file that doesn't require such a high version, or does Meson use Ninja features only available in 1.5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as you can see in meson git repository, [ninja minimum version was raised from 1.3.4 to 1.5.1](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/commit/4cfb3f19473d602761e59e1f1a5e5dd24eb286b8) on December 3 2014 for the following reason:

> To celebrate the new version of Ninja in Debian, start using the console pool.

One solution would be to use an older meson-build version (basically MAXIMUM version 0.21.0).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I tell Meson to generate a Ninja build file that doesn't require such a high version

No.  It's [hard coded in the meson source code](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/0.39.1/mesonbuild/backend/ninjabackend.py#L187).

> does Meson use Ninja features only available in 1.5.1?

Yes.  It's [the Console Pool](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_the_literal_console_literal_pool).